# How does Eclipse differentiate JDK and JRE for the "Installed JREs"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a jdk1.8.0_92 installed, which is also added to the Java/Installed JREs in Eclipse Neon. The "bin" subfolder containing the java compiler and all other components of a standard JDK is there. Still, when I try to assign this JRE as a "Server Runtime Environment" of a GlassFish server, Eclipse complains it needs a JDK and not a JRE. An older jdk1.7.0_55 folder does not produce this problem, it is considered to be a JDK by Eclipse, and not a JRE. What may be missing from the 1.8 installation, by which Eclipse categorizes it as a JRE?  Image of the error message :

[image]

Comment: thought it would be defined by your JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: You can select the Java location to be used for a server, which is managed by Eclipse. So it can not be assigned to a single environment variable, you can have multiple servers defined in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, check [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/fixing-glassfish-jdk-path-problem-solved)

glassfish\config\asenv.bat

where java path is configured

REM set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre/..
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92

Comment: That would change the JVM in which Eclipse is running, won't it? This is not my question, please check the image link in the question, maybe that makes it more clear.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is already set as you suggested.I am afraid it is still misunderstood. I don't want to change the JRE running Eclipse. I want to assign a JDK to a GlassFish server in Eclipse, but Eclipse does not recognize it as a JDK, but as a JRE.

Comment: That would probably help when running GlassFish from command line, but makes no difference for a server in Eclipse.